# IIF column comparison in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

How do we do following column comparison in Sybase (isql)

```
SELECT.....
FROM
WHERE IIF(Col1 = "4", "00", Col1)  = Mid (Col4,1,2)
```

I tried below, but didn't succeed

```
SELECT ...
FROM
WHERE
(case
      when Col1 = "4" then "00"
      else Col1
end)  = Mid (Col4,1,2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**substring**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks215.htm) function instead of `Mid`.

```
SELECT ...
FROM
WHERE
(case
      when Col1 = "4" then "00"
      else Col1
end)  = substring(Col4,1,2)
```

Comment: Thax Parado. Got you. Can you let me know what is the corresponding function for `replace() ` ans `Instr() ` in Sybase isql. Because these wont highlight as keywords in isql IDE

Comment: @ManthreePeiris `replace` is `str_replace`.  `Instr` is something like `CHARINDEX`.